# SharePoint 2013 file upload with Jquery

Tags: sharepoint

I am currently developing a page which users will be able to upload from their local machines files to a sharepoint 2013 server.

Currently I have managed to experiment with the ajax calls and use the rest api for creating simple .txt files and additional folders.

The problem I am facing is a response I am getting when trying to upload a .doc file or any other file that is using an arrayBuffer as the data.

Here is my code (which again is working is the data passed is a simple string:

```
url = "http://temp-sharepoint/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='"+fileName+"')";

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                     "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                },
               success: doSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
```

The code above will result in a response of

[object Error]{description: "The paramet...", message: "The paramet...", name: "Error", number: -2147024809, stack: "Error: The ..."}

which is "The Parameter is incorrect."

Again if data is "Test" the file is being created with no problems.

I am quite new to sharepoint and I would appreciate if someone can point me to a possible solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading file into buffer check if it contains proper data while debugging using browser debugger

Sample code for uploading file

```
function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {
    var url = String.format(
        "{0}/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Project Documents')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
        _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: buffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: function getFileBuffer(fileInput) {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

Comment: I can output the arraybuffer in the console or do a base64 transform. I am using the example code for calling REST. Not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a lot and you are using nintex (very similar to jquery)

```
  NWF$("#getFile").on('change', function () {
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // IFFY to save the current index
        (function (x) {
            var file = files[x];
            lastFileName = file.name;
            var fileName = Date.now() + file.name;
            var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
                //alert('in getFileBuffer');
                var deferred = NWF$.Deferred();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
                }
                reader.onerror = function (e) {
                    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                return deferred.promise();
            };


            getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
                //alert(buffer);
                NWF$.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + fileName + "')",
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: "Contents of file",
                    data: buffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        "ACCEPT": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                        // "content-length": buffer.byteLength
                    }, //end headers
                    success: function (data) {
                        ++indexFile;
                        console.log(data);
                        var fileUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        NWF$('#displayFiles tr:last').after('<tr><td><a class="fileLink" href="' + fileUrl + '">' + lastFileName + '</a></td><td><a class="removeHyper">מחיקה &times</a></td></tr>');
                        filesItems.push(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + data.d.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        NWF$('#' + filesList).text(converAddressToString(filesItems))
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("err " + data.d);
                    }
                });
            })
        })(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try using this if you need to upload multiple items too with file type and size restrictions.

var appWebUrl, hostWebUrl;

jquery(document).ready(function () {

    // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
    }

    // Get the add-in web and host web URLs.
    appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
});

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {

    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    // The display name must be unique every time you run the example.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

            // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('file uploaded and updated');
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
            });
            getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
            appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

        // Construct the endpoint.
        // The list item URI uses the host web, but the cross-domain call is sent to the
        // add-in web and specifies the host web as the context site.
        fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace(hostWebUrl, '{0}');
        fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');

        var listItemAllFieldsEndpoint = String.format(fileListItemUri + "?@target='{1}'",
            appWebUrl, hostWebUrl);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: listItemAllFieldsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }

    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

        // Construct the endpoint.
        // Specify the host web as the context site.
        var listItemUri = itemMetadata.uri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');
        var listItemEndpoint = String.format(listItemUri + "?@target='{0}'", hostWebUrl);

        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title.
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: listItemEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": body.length,
                "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}

// Get parameters from the query string.
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```